# Use current year as range validation in DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

```
[Range(1900, DateTime.Now.Year, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid year")]
```

This doesn't work.  For "DateTime.Now.Year" it tells me

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

Comment: That's a pretty clear message. Did you have a question?

Comment: Based on the error, this probably isn't possible. I think your next best option would be to write your own annotation, and wrap the Range annotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create your own *RangeUntilCurrentYearAttribute* that extends the *RangeAttribute*.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RangeUntilCurrentYearAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public RangeUntilCurrentYearAttribute(int minimum) : base(minimum, DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [RangeUntilCurrentYear(1900, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class YearRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int m_min;
    private Range m_range;

    public YearRangeAttribute(int min)
    {
        m_min = min
        m_range = new Range(min, DateTime.Now.Year);
    }


    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return m_range.IsValid(value)
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return m_range.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }
}
```

<sup>Disclaimer: This is untested, free-hand code.</sup>